# dc.js generate a pieChart with top 5 values

Tags: javascript, charts, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm visualizing a drug database of 200 entries. I've created a piechart using DC.js to show the frequency of each drug. The pie chart is cluttered with drugs that appear once.

I want to adjust this pie chart so that it visualizes the top 5 most used drugs i.e. the top 5 biggest slices of the pie chart.

Is there a way to use the .group() or .reduceSum() methods so only the biggest pie chart slices are shown?

Comment: Do you know in advance which 5 drugs you want in your pie chart ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [answered on the user group](https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/dc-js-user-group/3cbee7b9-9ab3-463a-ac3b-e39f00ad5a82%40googlegroups.com?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer): Use the functions of the [Cap Mixin](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#cap-mixin), which is a base of the pie chart:

```
var pie = dc.pieChart("#pie-chart");
[...]
pie.cap(5);
```

Comment: I think SO provides a better reference for posterity, so I prefer to answer questions here. (But I guess the user group grabs my attention more quickly.)